# django url tag: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering

Tags: django, django-urls

```
#urls.py
places_url_regex = ur'''
    ^places
    (
    (?:/types/(?P<types>\d+(?:-\d+)*))
    |
    (?:/cuisines/(?P<cuisines>\d+(?:-\d+)*))
    |
    (?:/avg-bills/(?P<avg_bills>\d+(?:-\d+)*))
    |
    (?:/cities/(?P<cities>\d+(?:-\d+)*))
    |
    (?:/sectors/(?P<sectors>\d+(?:-\d+)*))
    |
    (?:/streets/(?P<streets>\d+(?:-\d+)*))
    |
    (?:/special/(?P<special>[cabins|calian|children\-animation|children\-room|parking|summer\-verandah|vip-room|wifi|smokers\-room]+))
    |
    (?:/with/(?P<w>[discounts]+))
    |
    (?:/page/(?P<page>\d+))
    )*
    /$
'''
places_url_regex = re.sub( ur'\s+', '', places_url_regex )
urlpatterns = patterns( '',
    url( places_url_regex, 'app.places.views.places', name = 'url_places' ),
)
#views.py
def places(request, page = 1, special = '', types = '', cuisines = '', avg_bills = '', cities = '', sectors = '', streets = '', w = ''):
    ...
```

if I manually open url `/places/types/10/` in address bar or in template `{% url url_places %}` it's works,
but in template `{% url url_places types=10 %}` raises exception: 
`Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'url_places' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'types': 10}' not found.` 
Why and how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of how to handle URLs with Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: `Could not parse the remainder: '=10' from '"types"=10'`

Comment: that makes sense. As a matter of interest, why aren't you using the conventional approach to urls?

Comment: what the conventional approach ?

Comment: it's funny. If i change regex to: `url( ur'^places/$', 'app.places.views.places', name = 'url_places' ),
    url( ur'^places(?:/types/(?P<types>\d+(?:-\d+)*))/$', 'app.places.views.places' ),` url tag works